# Generic SIMD code in LLVM-IR for string search

Tags: c++17, simd, clang++, llvm-ir, avx

I was looking at [simdcsv](https://github.com/geofflangdale/simdcsv/blob/master/src/main.cpp) library, to try to understand the basics of what they do, how they speed up delimiter search.

This is a portion of their `cmp_mask_against_input` function:

```
#include "intrin.h"
#include <cstdint>

struct simd_input {
  __m256i lo;
  __m256i hi;
};

inline uint64_t cmp_mask_against_input(simd_input in, uint8_t m) {

      const __m256i mask = _mm256_set1_epi8(m);
      __m256i cmp_res_0 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(in.lo, mask);
      uint64_t res_0 = static_cast<uint32_t>(_mm256_movemask_epi8(cmp_res_0));
      __m256i cmp_res_1 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(in.hi, mask);
      uint64_t res_1 = _mm256_movemask_epi8(cmp_res_1);
      return res_0 | (res_1 << 32);

}

int main () {

}
```

This works on CPUs that support AVX2. My older machine has only SSE2, and I assume everything in between needs its own `#ifdef` with different commands etc.

I was wondering - if I don't mind that my code only compiles on Clang - is it feasible to create a "generic" IR version of a string search, that Clang will than convert to the proper cmpeq/move commands?

Comment: Have you tried using the sse2 equivalents that work on 128 bit wide registers ?  All you need to do is replace _m256 by mm or _m128 in the operands and data types.  Tghe only exceptio, are the movemask operations, but these can be done with mm128 operations.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy: I think the point is to write it once and have LLVM expand it to actual asm using the widest (or best choice) of vector width supported.  With AVX512 having different compare-into-mask instructions, you'd want a slightly different inner loop, like doing two compares into 64-bit masks and using `kortest k0, k1` to see if either mask has any set bits.  I have no idea if even 128-bit vs. 256-bit vectorization could be done generically in LLVM-IR; for C++ you need a template wrapper library around intrinsics, like Agner Fog's.

Comment: Well, 256 bit wide operations are not supported by sse2 machines.  You need to realize that each mmx intrinsics correspond to a single cpu operation. Using these intrinsics is like writing assembly code. It's very low-level, on purpose.  It's not uncommon to have several versions of the same code for sse2; sse3, avx256,  avx512 and no mmx optimization in production code, with the code to run being selected at runtime.

Comment: The function loads several copies of the character to match in `mask`,   then compares the 64 bytes from input for equality with `mask`, Since a _m256i value only holds 32 bytes, the comparison is do ne in two stages. The resulting bit masks of the two compares are concatenated into a single 64-bit interger and returned.

Comment: Strangely, when trying to implement this manually [like so](https://godbolt.org/z/C2nan6), clang uses a `vpmovmskb`, but then splits the result into individual bits just to join them back together afterwards ...

Comment: have you looked at `SCASB` instruction? These are meant for string search